# not possible to define height of logo in @bottom-right

Tags: python, html, css, pdf-generation, weasyprint

We are using weasyprint to generate a pdf and are trying to place our logo in the footer. For this, we need to adjust the height / width of the image.

```
<style type="text/css">
@page {
   @bottom-right {
      content: url("xxx.png");
      height: 20px;
      width: auto;
   }
}
```

however, this is not working. weasyprint states in the documentation, that they do not support following CSS 2.1 features (among others):

- Minimum and maximum width and height on page-margin boxes.
  [weasyprint documentation](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#css-level-2-revision-1)

any advice how to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried removing the space between 20 & px

Comment: I have this only in the question, not in actual code. thx for the hint. I edited the question